# Getting access token from Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

public class pred {
    public static String getGoogleAccessToken(String jsonKeyFilePath)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream(jsonKeyFilePath)).createScoped(
                Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));

        credential.refreshToken();

        return credential.getAccessToken();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        String a=getGoogleAccessToken("D:ml-latest-small\\untitled\\src\\woven*************.json");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I want to get access token to get prediction from a version deployed in the google cloud. Above code 
gives an access token to google drive. Is there a way to change this part (DriveScopes.DRIVE) to get 
an access token to google cloud. Or is there a another way to get access token from java.

Comment: Where is you code is running? And what do you want to achieve? To have an access token with the Drive scope and the Cloud Platform scope? Do you want to use the default credential and not use the credential key file? What is your challenge?

Comment: See [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java). You can scope to [`cloud-platform`](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict#authorization-scopes)